# Sql Group By Max Value in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been pulling my hair out all day on this, could anyone help me. I think it's probably pretty simple but I can't quite get exactly what I want.

The data in the table looks like this

```
CallId      ProblemDescription  CurrentAction     CurrentEngineer    EventNumber
CON-00002                       Respond to Call                      0
WHS-00001                       Respond to Call                      0
WHS-00002                       Respond to Call                      0
WHS-00003                       Respond to Call                      0
WHS-00003                       Fix Problem                          1
WHS-00003                       Problem Fixed                        2
```

What I would like to do is to display all columns foreach CallId with the maximum event number. I.e.

```
CallId      ProblemDescription  CurrentAction     CurrentEngineer    EventNumber
CON-00002                       Respond to Call                      0
WHS-00001                       Respond to Call                      0
WHS-00002                       Respond to Call                      0
WHS-00003                       Problem Fixed                        2
```

However I cant figure out how to do it.

At the moment I'm using

```
Select CallId, MAX(ProblemDescription), MAX(CurrentAction), MAX(CurrentEngineer),
MAX(EventNumber) FROM [Table] GROUP BY CallId
```

How this obviously returns the maximum for every coloumn individually. So in the case above the CurrentAction column shows `Respond to Call` not `Respond to Call`

Could anyone show me how to do this???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are looking for [`DENSE_RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
      CallId, 
      ProblemDescription, 
      CurrentAction, 
      CurrentEngineer, 
      EventNumber,
      Rank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CallId ORDER BY EventNumber DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT 
   CallId, ProblemDescription, CurrentAction, CurrentEngineer, EventNumber
FROM 
   CTE
WHERE 
   RANK = 1
```

If you want only one row per `CallId` even if there are multiple with the same max `EventNumber` use `ROW_NUMBER` instead.

Comment: As it happens, (and I should have included this in my question), the primary key for table is a combination of Call_Id and EventNumber so this is the best way of achieving it. However the other method given by @Gordon Linoff works great too.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use row_number() for this:

```
select CallId, ProblemDescription, CurrentAction, CurrentEngineer, EventNumber
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by callId order by eventnumber desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.
* Use Max aggregate only on Event Number Column.

```
SELECT CallID, Problem_Description, Current_Action, Current_Engineer, MAX( Event_Number ) FROM test.data GROUP BY CallID;
```

This might help you